# How does Audiobus for iOS work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What SDK's does [Audiobus](http://audiob.us) use to provide inter-app audio routing? I am not aware of any Apple SDK that could facilitate inter-app communication for iOS and was under the impression that apps were sandboxed from each other so I'm really intrigued to hear how they pulled this off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS allows inter-app communication via MIDI Sysex messages. AudioBus works by sending audio as MIDI Sysex message.  You can read details from the developer himself:

http://atastypixel.com/blog/thirteen-months-of-audiobus/

Comment: The linked post says it was initially based on SysEx messages, but eventually they switched to Mach ports for increased performance.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that they use some sort of audio over network, because I've seen log statements when our app gets started even on a different device.

Don't really know about the details of the implementation, but this could be a way of staying in the "sandbox" constraint.

Comment: No. iOS allows inter-app communication via MIDI Sysex messages. AudioBus works by sending audio through as MIDI Sysex message.

Answer (score 1):

The Audiobus SDK (probably) use the [Audio Session](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Basics/Basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW1) rules to "organize" all the sound output from the apps using their SDK, as you can see on their [videos](http://audiob.us/press) (on bottom of the page), the apps have an lateral menu to switch back and forwards between apps.

The Audio Session Category states:

> Allows mixing: if yes, audio from other applications (such as the iPod) can continue playing when your application plays sound.

This way Audiobus can "control" the sound and allow the session to be persistent between the apps.

Comment: I'm part of the Audiobus team. We've developed our own SDK for this, and as has been mentioned before it's basically a network protocol. We're planning to make the Audiobus SDK public soon(TM).
If you'd like to have a look at it even sooner, please contact us here: http://audiob.us/support